# How to compile .py into an executable for Debian

Tags: python, compilation, debian

I'm having a hard time finding a conclusive answer for how to compile a Python 2.7 .py file into a executable program for Debian. Most tutorials say "we assume you've already written the manifest, etc.", but I cannot find how to do those first steps.

So, I need a step-by-step. How do I take JUST a .py file (using Python 2.7 and PyGTK) and a few .pdf and .png files that go with it, and compile all of that into a working Debian binary?

(Note: If the tutorial starts out with a tar.gz, or requires a setup.py or similar already written, I need instructions on how to get those files too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

deb files are packages: an archive that extracts files into certain predetermined places and may run some configuration scripts. It really depends on how the developer needs to deploy the package. A python file may be a part of a deb package, but once it's deployed and extracted it is extracted as a python file. If you need a binary version of a python file, you will need to [look at other means](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

Take a look at the following:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/

Comment: I had forgotten about PyInstaller. Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 4):

A `.deb` file is not an "executable program", it is a [package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_package_%28installation%29). Building a Debian package does not involve compiling, but rather, well, "packaging".

A good introduction to building Debian packages is the [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/).

Comment: Correction, then...how do I compile into an executable that will run on debian.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you need to compile it? Debian, like most other Linux distributions, comes with Python installed as standard, as many of the system tools depend on it. A Python script will just run.

Comment: I want it compiled. I just do. If I wanted to run the script every time, I'd have done that, thank you.